# How to build apk file that is upto date in IBM MobileFirst 8?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have one basic question regarding MobileFirst 8.
In MobileFirst 7.1 we tend to build wlapp file and deploy it on server which provides soft updates to existing app user. If I build the apk file with same resources as of wlapp file, it won't take update as its resources are already upto date.

We don't have wlapp file in MobileFirst 8. We can deliver update through web update command. But how do I build apk or ipa file that contains latest resources and won't take any soft update.

Currently, I am building webupdate zip, upload it to MFP Server and then build apk, but then also it is asking for update. Is there any specific commands I have to execute?

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you create and build the Cordova project using Cordova tools. To generate the .apk file, consult the Android and/or Cordova documentation.

MobileFirst Foundation comes to play only once you add the cordova-plug-mfp plug-in, which is the MobileFirst SDK for Cordova applications.

Also, as you mentioned, the concept of a .wlapp file is no more. There is no need (or way...) to deploy this file to the MobileFirst Server. Instead,  you only **register** the application in the MobileFirst Server either via the MobileFirst Operations Console or the MobileFirst CLI.

Once you want to use the Direct Update feature, you can follow these steps:

1. Make changes in your application JavaScript/CSS/HTML
2. Propagate your changes to the native project in Cordova by using the `cordova prepare` command
3. Deploy the updated web resources to the MobileFirst Server by using the `mfpdev app webupdate` command

The next time the application will attempt to access a **secured resource** that is protected by the MobileFirst Server, the request to the server will also check for updated resources. If updated resources are found, these will be presented to the end user to update the application.

Once an update has taken place, the application will no longer check for updates for as long as the token the app received from the server is valid. The expiration value of the token is 60 minutes. So for the next 60 minutes the application will not be able to receive direct updates.

> Throughout this process there is no need to re-build the .apk file and do anything with it. This is all about the *web resources* of the application.
>
> You only need to build a new .apk file if you intend to submit a new *application version* to the Google Play Store.

Repeat this process for future direct updates.
Learn more about Direct Update, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/